# AVPlayer cannot service a synchronized playback request via setRate:time:atHostTime: until its status is AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, synchronization

I am trying to write a rather simple iOS app synchronizing the playback of a video with AVPlayer (from AVFoundation) to audio playback from multiple AKPlayers (Audiokit 4.0), using the .setRate function of AVPlayer together with CMClockGetHostTimeClock() and mach_absolute_time().

For some reason all my attempts end in the error message

> AVPlayer cannot service a synchronized playback request via setRate:time:atHostTime: until its status is AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay.

Obviously I keep on missing something. The movie plays just fine if I replace everything starting from "let time..." with a simple
`videoPlayer.play()`

This is a minimal "ViewController.swift" to reproduce the error:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var videoPlayer = AVPlayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let videopath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "mov") else {
            debugPrint("test.mov not found")
            return
        }
        
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videopath)
        videoPlayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view!.bounds
        self.view!.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        
        let time: TimeInterval = 1 // 1 second in the future
        
        videoPlayer.masterClock = CMClockGetHostTimeClock()
        
        let hostTime = mach_absolute_time()
        
        let cmHostTime = CMClockMakeHostTimeFromSystemUnits(hostTime)
        let cmVTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, preferredTimescale: videoPlayer.currentTime().timescale)
        let futureTime = CMTimeAdd(cmHostTime, cmVTime)
        videoPlayer.setRate(1, time: CMTime.invalid, atHostTime: futureTime)
        
        
    }
    
}
```